# random_seed in gfortran leads to memory leak?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Valgrind reports blocks that are still reachable when using the `random_seed` routine.
Is it expected, is it a bug in gfortran, or am I missing something ?

For instance, the following program, when compiled with `gfortran`:

`rng.f90`

```
program rng
  implicit none

  integer :: n

  call random_seed(size=n)
end program rng
```

leads to the following report by `valgrind`:

```
==233092== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==233092==    at 0x484A464: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1328)
==233092==    by 0x4893EF6: _gfortrani_xcalloc (memory.c:78)
==233092==    by 0x4AF0DCE: get_rand_state (random.c:248)
==233092==    by 0x4AF0DCE: get_rand_state (random.c:238)
==233092==    by 0x4AF0DCE: _gfortran_random_seed_i4 (random.c:889)
==233092==    by 0x401168: MAIN__ (in /home/baptiste/dev/misc/f90/rng/rng)
==233092==    by 0x40119F: main (in /home/baptiste/dev/misc/f90/rng/rng)
==233092== 
==233092== LEAK SUMMARY:
==233092==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==233092==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==233092==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==233092==    still reachable: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==233092==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==233092==
```

`gfortran` version: GNU Fortran (GCC) 12.2.1 20220819 (Red Hat 12.2.1-2)

I compiled the program above using: `gfortran -o rng rng.f90`

Comment: Are you asking what "still reachable" means and whether you should worry about it, or _are_ worried about still reachable blocks and want to know how to prevent them?

Comment: @francescalus: oh yes, there is that!

Comment: That was more of a curiosity, to know why this particular routine leads to still reachable blocks. I was cleaning the errors / warnings reported by valgrind in my program, and came across this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

This is (minor) bug somewhere, potentially in how valgrind handles stuff like thread destructors. In GFortran each thread has it's own PRNG state, which is allocated lazily the first time it's needed, and then freed by the thread destructor.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/git?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libgfortran/intrinsics/random.c;h=b5732e6c25a14359745c5f698c2dd4cab6f3c81f;hb=HEAD#l238 for the get_rand_state() function which the various higher level routines use to access the PRNG state, and https://gcc.gnu.org/git?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libgfortran/intrinsics/random.c;h=b5732e6c25a14359745c5f698c2dd4cab6f3c81f;hb=HEAD#l1034 for the constructor and destructor functions.